# How to right align an array of numbers in Ruby Shoes?

Tags: ruby, shoes

Tried `align: right` and `sprintf`, but for some reason it does not do a right alignment.

```
[ 50, 100, 50 ]

 50
100
 50
```

Is this a limitation of Shoes 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this with green shoes since i don't use Shoes4 but it should be the same.

```
Shoes.app do
  flow do
    [ 50, 100, 50 ].each do |number|
      para number, :align => 'right'
    end
  end
end
```